# Error launching tomcat while migrating from java7 tomcat7 to java8 tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, java-8, tomcat8

I'm making the switch to Java 8 tomcat 8 on a project that uses tomcat 7 java 7.

I've recompiled the sources without errors.

My problem comes running tomcat.

I can't connect to a resource using this conf :

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource
            name="shared/jdbc/toto"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="toto"
            password="toto"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://syt-db:5432/toto"
            maxActive="4"
            maxIdle="2"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

I get this error :

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

I added the factory as seen somewhere on the internet.

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource
            name="shared/jdbc/toto"
            auth="Container"
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            type="javax.sql.DataSourceFactory"
            username="toto"
            password="toto"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
            url="jdbc:postgresql://syt-db:5432/toto"
            maxActive="4"
            maxIdle="2"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

and got an error like this :

```
AVERTISSEMENT [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup Une erreur s est produite durant la résolution de la référence
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The local resource link [toto] that refers to global resource [shared/jdbc/toto] does not specify the required attribute type
```

I feel like now it can use the driver but still has a wrong configuration.

Is my problem really coming from the resource conf or should I focus on something else ?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add the type="javax.sql.DataSource" in the context of my application

```
 <ResourceLink
   name="jdbc/toto"
   global="shared/jdbc/toto"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  />
```

You need to write the type in the ressource definition and in the context of your server.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to copy the jar-file with the postgres-driver from your old tomcat7 into the new tomcat 8.

Look in the TOMCAT_HOME/lib - directory for the file.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't seem to change anything.